# display 2 type datepicker in one (gregorian & jalali)

Tags: datepicker, gregorian-calendar, jalali-calendar

I have a plugin for show Gregorian and Jalali Datepicker:

https://amirkabirdataminers.github.io/ADM-dateTimePicker/

But I want show both in one calendar as in example.

exm: `<span>Day Jalali<br>Day Gregorian</span>`

[image: exm image]

please help me how can i this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/babakhani/pwt.datepicker
It’s a good library that supports both Jalali and Gregorian Date format with many options. Also, you can customize its template if the design is important to you.